# How to center graphics with small page size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, margins, geometry

I need to make many graphics, all of which have the same page size, and all of which are centered. The page size is quite small, as the graphics are going side by side in tables. I do not want to scale them because that will distort them and make them ugly. I have almost solved the problem but I cannot get the graphic to be centered.

Here is the code:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex

\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=0pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in, top=0in, footskip=0in, bottom=0in,paperwidth=3cm,paperheight=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,graphdrawing,arrows.meta,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{countme}
\setcounter{countme}{0}
\newcommand*\countup{\stepcounter{countme}\thecountme}
\newcommand*\countset{\setcounter{countme}{0}}
\tikzset{%
  edge counter/.style={"\countup"} 
}
\tikz[>=Stealth,]{%
  \graph [simple necklace layout, grow=left, node sep=10mm, nodes={circle },  edge quotes center, edge quotes={fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize}]
  {
%    subgraph C_n [n=4, -!-];
    { [edges={edge counter,}] 
       0 [black!100] -> 1 };
  };
}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

How can I CENTER the graphic in the middle of the page, and moreover do it generally for different graphics and different page sizes?

Comment: you seem to have succeeded in centering the image horizontally, but if this is a problem, `\centering` should work, or `\[ ... \]` if it's math.  to center vertically, put `\vspace*{\fill}` at the top; i believe a two-l fill is the default at the bottom, and the asterisk form of `\vspace` keeps it from disappearing at the top of a page.

Comment: `\vspace*{\fill}` did not work for me. it moved the graphic to the bottom of the page (same place it is occupying in the image above, only at the bottom). did you try it with my code?

Comment: i didn't try it with your code; i don't typically use `scrartcl` or lualatex (the environment i work in requires "production-reliable" tools, which luatex has not been up to now).  but i've actually tried it now, and find that `\vspace{.5\fill}` above and `\vspace{\fill}` below appears to center *this* example; whether that will carry over to all examples isn't certain.  something is going on with this particular environment that isn't obvious -- trying to attach a factor to the `\fill` at the end doesn't do at all what i expected -- so this suggestion is really just a wild guess.

Comment: You may try the `standalone` class instead of `article`...